# To Get the query string value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code but it is not running properly.

```
function QueryStringParam1(d) {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var q = document.URL.split('?')[0];   
        if (q != undefined) {
            q = q.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
                hash = q[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[1]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
        }
        return vars[d];
    }
```

Comment: Where is this function used and what is it expected to do?

Comment: What output is expected?

Comment: what is the use of `d` parameter?

Comment: Asked too many times. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+querystring

Comment: the d parameter is a query string name

Comment: should be `var q = document.URL.split('?')[1]` if you want the query string

Comment: This function is to get query string value from Id

Comment: `document` object hasn't `URL` property. You have to use `location.href` instead

Comment: Check this alternative: http://techtaunt.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/querystring-to-json/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to get query string value from this query. So you would be getting string having its value after '?' char.

So  after split relevant string should be in 1 index not 0..
replace

```
var q = document.URL.split('?')[0];
```

by

```
var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
```